# Cakephp find threaded without "Children"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm setting up an API and would rather just have objects in my array instead of "Modelname" & "Children" repeatedly sprinkled throughout.  Is there a way to do this?  I imagine a loop would do the trick but I can't figure it out.

```
      $results = $this->Test->find('threaded', array(
    'fields' => array('id', 'parent_id', 'name'),
      'order' => array('lft ASC') // or array('id ASC')
      ));

  for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->Test->childCount(1); $i++) {
  debug($results[$i]['children']);

  }

  $this->set(array(
    'results' => $results,
    '_serialize' => 'results'
    ));
```

Comment: Which version of Cake? Could you show an example of the find query you're using and how you want the results to look.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you want your results array to look? Are you just wanting a flat array with the children at the same depth as the parents?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if the code you provided is pretty non-unique to both 3.x and 2.x, so I'll share solutions for each.

**3.x**

You can get a flat list of all of the descendants of tree node by passing in 'children' as the finder type into your query:

```
$result = $this->Test->find('children', array(
    'for' => $record_id,   // Notice you have to specify 'for' key!
    'fields' => array('id', 'parent_id', 'name'),
    'order' => array('lft ASC')
));
```

If you only want to find direct children of your node, pass in true for the 'direct' key in your options array:

```
$result = $this->Test->find('children', array(
    'for' => $record_id,   // Notice you have to specify 'for' key!
    'fields' => array('id', 'parent_id', 'name'),
    'order' => array('lft ASC'),
    'direct' => true
));
```

More Info:

[3.x Cookbook for TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#a-quick-tour)

[3.x findChildren() defined in API](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TreeBehavior.html#390-437)

[3.x API Info for findChildren()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TreeBehavior.html#_findChildren)

**2.x**

To get a flat list of all descendents in 2.x, you utilize the ->children() function provided by the TreeBehavior class:

```
$result = $this->Test->children(
    $record_id,                   // ID of record to find children for 
    false,                        // Direct = false 
    ['id', 'parent_id', 'name'],  // Fields to include in query
    'lft ASC'                     // Order
)
```

Conversely, to find direct descendants only, you would pass in the second argument as true:

```
$result = $this->Test->children(
    $record_id,                   // ID of record to find children for 
    true,                         // Direct = true 
    ['id', 'parent_id', 'name'],  // Fields to include in query
    'lft ASC'                     // Order
)
```

More Info:

[2.x Cookbook for TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::children)

[2.x children() defined in API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-TreeBehavior.html#295-361)

[2.x API Info for children()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-TreeBehavior.html#_children)

The CakePHP TreeBehavior does a great job of abstracting away a lot of the pains with working with Tree data.  I hope this information helps!